# PyGtk buttons changing when window is unfocused

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a small problem with styling buttons in Gtk.

I am using CssProvider to style the buttons, and I've been able to get them to look how I like for the most part. The problem seems to be some styling built into Gtk that adds styling to the buttons when the window is focused.

Example:
[Focused window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhaOn.png), [Unfocused window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWUvy.png)

As you can see, when the window is focused all the buttons get some lines drawn on the top and bottom, and the text gets bolded. I've been unable to get rid of these using both python and css.

Here's a chunk of my css. I couldn't get background-color to work so I'm using a hacky gradient solution. Maybe this is the problem?

```
.button {
    border-style: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear,
                                     left top,
                                     left bottom,
                                     from (#2196F3),
                                     to (#2196F3));

    border-radius: 1px;
    border-width: 0px;   
}

.button:active {
    background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear,
                                     left top,
                                     left bottom,
                                     from (#1D83D4),
                                     to (#1D83D4));
    border-style: none;

}

#window { 
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

I've messed with a couple Gtk functions trying to disable focusing, but haven't had much luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your empty border-style with simply no border like:

```
border: none;
```

does the problem persist?